# why is ? a reserved character in HTML?

Tags: html, entities

The `<`, `>` characters are reserved because they define start and end of an html tag, `&` is reserved as it defines start of a character entity as in `&nbsp;`
But what I am not able to figure out is what is the role that the character `?` plays?

Comment: From where did you get the idea of Reserved characters in HTML?

Comment: I think he means that the `<` character is part of the syntax of HTML

Comment: What do you mean by the use of `?`?

Comment: are you talking about CGI / query params ?

Comment: Where is the `?` giving you trouble? What makes you think it is 'reserved'?

Comment: Did you mean `"` instead of `?` ... ?

Comment: It will be used in php. <?php  ?>. But it will not make trouble in html. and You can use Special Character &#63; in html

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at these docs for understanding character entity references in HTML (the docs pertain to HTML 4):

1. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html (Character Entity References)
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html (HTML Document Representation)
3. http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html (Coded Character Set)

From the sections, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3.2 and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.4 :

> Four character entity references deserve special mention since they
>   are frequently used to escape special characters:
>
> "<" represents the < sign.
>
> ">" represents the > sign.
>
> "&" represents the & sign.
>
> "" represents the " mark.

They have a special mention, but still aren't *reserved*. The reason you escape them is to avoid unintentional parsing of markup.

The list is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.4.1 and here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

`?` although represented by `&#63;` (or `&quest;`) is not used to escape because it is not a special character to be used in markup.